# Prove or disprove that the minimum finite value of $y=\frac{\sin(nx)}{(\sin x)^n}$ occurs only at $n=3,5$ for $n>1, \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**Question**:- Prove or disprove that the minimum finite value  of $$y=\frac{\sin(nx)}{(\sin x)^n}$$ occurs only at $n=3,5$ for $n>1,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Recently, in a question I was asked to find minimum value of $y=\frac{\sin(5x)}{(\sin x)^5}$, I got $\frac{-1}{4}$ as minimum value. So I tried to find minimum value for other values of $n$.

Using graph, I figured out that only for $n=3,5$, graph have minimum finite value of $-1$ and  $\frac{-1}{4}$ respectively. For other values of $n$ the minimum value is $-\infty$.

So I want to know what is special with $3$ and $5$ but not with other values or are there any other values of $n$ apart from $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122031/prove-that-frac-sinnx-sinnx-for-natural-n-only-has-minimum-value)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but I could not understand the answer well Since it is only partial answer and my question is why it is minimum for $n=3,5$

Comment: @Paras I think that [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122031/prove-that-frac-sinnx-sinnx-for-natural-n-only-has-minimum-value) is enough if you fully understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false. The function has (global) minimum for every odd value of $n$.

Indeed since the numerator of the expression is bounded, the function can go to infinity only at zeros of the denominator, i.e. at $x=\pi k,\;k\in\mathbb Z$. For odd values of $n$ it is easy to check that the function is even and periodic with period $\pi$. It is positive for $|x|<\frac\pi n$. Therefore at both sides of $k\pi$ it goes to $+\infty$. This excludes the possibility that the function can go to $-\infty$ at some point.

Particularly for $n=7$ the minimum of the function is $-64$ and is attained at $x=\pm\frac\pi6+\pi k$.